# How to control application via webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to control application (in my case it is corelDraw) ,I know I should use it's application object and I do this, but the issue now is I want to do this in webservice,
so as far as I understand if I put this code which control the application in the web-service ,my code will try to control the corel application which is on the server not on the client :(

so any hint/advice how could I do this, and control the application on the client not server ?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already noticed web service runs on server and only result is passed to client. 
Well you have a few options to control client machine over web service... Here is one of possible scenarios. 
1. create web service that will provide commands for client
2. create windows service (client) that will consume your web service commands
3. inside windows service then just execute those commands in appropriate manner

Well I have to say this is not the prefered way I would take to automate corelDraw, but if you insist on using webservice as command provider it will do the job.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I thinks this means to see how the cmd compile -> run (on fly) the code which will be downloaded from the server ?!!

Comment: You can do that or just prebuid your commands inside the client. So we service will just send command like "StartCorel" or "OpenFile 'myFile'", etc... Here is link how to use Corel COM library http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoCDrw.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself what is the difference between client and a server. Can a client be a server? Can a server be a client?

You make your client with CorelDraw installed to accept web-service request, i.e. effectively make it a web-service server, and then carry on as normal.

Although I would say web-service is not the best way to control such complex application as CorelDraw. I'd look in some other ways of communication between peers, like lower level network communication that would not have overhead of HTTP.